# Как добавить функцию, чтобы отлавливать в XMLHttpRequest ошибки?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
   function query(opts){
        opts.beforeSend();
        var xhttp = getXhttp();
        xhttp.open("POST", "controller.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4){
              if(xhttp.status == 200){
                    opts.success(xhttp.responseText);
               }
        }
      }
        xhttp.send("action=updateCount");
   }
```

Есть 2 `callback`-функции: `beforeSend()`, `success()`.

Как мне теперь добавить еще одну функцию - `error()` (как в `ajax`), чтобы отлавливать в `XMLHttpRequest` любые ошибки?

Думаю, вы поняли, чего я хочу. Спасибо.

Comment: [Ловить xhttp.status][1]

   [1]:http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-status-%D0%B8-statustext

Comment: есть onerror. Или в onreadystatechange проверять на статус

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См. [эту статью](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest), особое внимание к [этому пункту](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#другие-события-загрузки).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(xhttp.status == 200){
    opts.success(xhttp.responseText);
}else{
    // ТУТ ОШИБКА!
    // 404, Инет не работает :) или какая нибудь другая.
    // Больше не знаю какие ошибки могут быть
}
```

Comment: 404 никак не означает, что инета нет, просто запрошенный ресурс не найден.  
Других состояний HTTP довольно много, [см. тут.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP)  
И вообще - хороший ответ уже дан, зачем давать плохой ответ?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что все ошибки в ELSE у него будут

Comment: Ха, т.е. 302-е состояние тоже ошибка? И 301, и 401, и... ну ты понял.